# Error cypress and paypal sdk "react-paypal-js"

Tags: reactjs, paypal, cypress

I have at error with cypress and paypal sdk "react-paypal-js" when I'm doing click in the paypal button I have the next error

"TypeError: o.removeEventListener is not a function"
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4uAe.png)

```html
import i18n from '@/lib/i18n';
import users from '@/cypress/fixtures/common/users';
describe('<InvoiceList />', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.task('db:seed:invoices');
  });
  after(() => {
    cy.task('db:clean', { db: 'elinvo' });
  });
  it('<InvoiceList /> - Validate app list', () => {
    cy.login({ email: users[1].email, password: 'usertimg' });
    cy.visit('/invoices');
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.get('[data-cy=invoice-btn-paypal]').click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's a bug in the `react-paypal-js` library or one of it's dependencies.

Add this at the top of your test to catch and ignore it,

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

Run the app in the browser, manually clicking the button.

Look in devtools console - is the error showing there?

This will confirm it's a paypal error and likely can be ignored.

Comment: Hi thanks!! I open the PayPal pop-up window, how can I access to log in? Is it possible to do this?. This window does not appear to be inside an iframe

Comment: Please raise that one in another question.